# R programming: perform function with switch functionality for each row based on different columns

Tags: r, function, switch-statement, dataframe

In R programming I try to do the following:

```
    df
    A       B     Category
    0.9     0.85  A
    0.7     0.75  B
    0.8     0.90  B

    CSF <- function(df, type) {
    switch(type,
               "A" = qnorm(df$A, 0 , 1),
               "B" = qnorm(df$B, 0 , 1)
    )
    }

    df<-data.frame(df, value = CSF(df,df$category))
```

Desired result:

```
    df
    A       B     Category     Value
    0.9     0.85  A            qnorm(0.9, 0, 1)*
    0.7     0.75  B            qnorm(0.75, 0, 1)*
    0.8     0.90  B            qnorm(0.9, 0, 1)*
```

*: real values

Error message: EXPR must be a length 1 vector

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ifelse` function:

```
df$Value <- ifelse(df$Category=="A",qnorm(df$A,0,1),qnorm(df$B,0,1))
```

Comment: Or even better: `qnorm(ifelse(df$Category=="A",df$A,df$B),0,1)`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. It works, however the dataset I am working with is a bit more complex. I have 12 different categories and each category has its own function which is more complex than the current formula's. I can use your approach but then I have to create something like ifelse(,,ifelse(,,(ifelse,,(ifelse..... which becomes unreadable and probably very slow. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance @ziggystar

Answer (score 0):

For a more complex arrangement of categories, I would recommend breaking it out into multiple statements.  Something like

```
df$CSF <- NA
df.split <- split(df, df$Category)
df.split$A$CSF <- qnorm(df.split$A$A, 0, 1)
df.split$B$CSF <- qnorm(df.split$B$B, 0, 1)
...
```

And then merge them back together

```
df <- unsplit(df.split, df$Category)
```

It doesn't have the elegance of a "single expression" but it also avoids having a huge amount of nesting to accomplish the task.  You could simplify the individual expressions using `within`:

```
df.split$A <- within(df.split$A, CSF <- qnorm(A, 0 0))
```